# Suggested tag replacements for linux-networking, windows-networking

Tags: support, retag-request

I think that instances of [linux-networking] should be replaced with [linux][networking] and [windows-networking] with [windows][networking]

I think doing this would be a good idea because having the two tags separate probably almost always means the same thing unless it was [linux][windows][networking]. Also, if we kept a dual purpose tag for linux and windows as we do now we may want one for solaris, unix, bsd or others.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about this myself, [*$OS*-networking] tags can (and should) refer to a specific feature or issue with networking on *$OS*.

Of course, if someone says "I'm on windows, and I can ping some things and not others" and tags that with [windows-networking] then that post should have its tags edited as its not a problem with *windows* networking, no arguments there.

Comment: Unless you see a difference between [$OS networking](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux+networking) and [$OS-networking](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-networking).. I still think that the latter should be replaced with the former. The former is more widely used and I doubt we will be making a variant of the latter for every OS.